# RxJS 5 subclassing Observable - static methods return instances of the parent class

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, reactivex

I'm trying to subclass the RxJS Observable class as described [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/doc/operator-creation.md) by subclassing Observable and overriding the lift method.

This works for any operators I add to the prototype, but whenever I try to instantiate a new Observable of my subclass (e.g. using MyObservable.from([1, 2, 3]), I get an Observable of the parent class.

How do I subclass Observable correctly, so that using Observable.return / Observable.from / works as expected? [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yecayosuko/edit?js,console)

```
class MyObservable extends Rx.Observable {
  lift(operator) {
    const observable = new MyObservable();
    observable.source = this;
    observable.operator = operator;
    return observable;
  }

  customOperator() {
    return this.map(arguments)
  }
}


// instantiating an observable with **MyObservable**.from
var observable = MyObservable.from([1, 2, 3]);
console.log('instance of Rx.Observable: ' + observable instanceof Rx.Observable);


// this works as map is defined on RxObservable
observable
  .map(value => console.log('standard ' + value)) 
  .subscribe();


// this doesn't work. customOperator is only defined on MyObservable
// and MyObservable.from([1, 2, 3]) returns an Rx.Observable instance
observable
  .customOperator(value => console.log('custom ' + value)) 
  .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an issue for this [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues/1124) and it turns out there's currently no clean solution to this.

Once [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/pull/1105) PR providing the let operator is merged the cleanest solution will be to wrap the original observable:

```
class MyObservable extends Observable {
  constructor(source) {
    this.source = source;
  }

  lift(operator) {
    const observable = new MyObservable(); //<-- important part here
    observable.source = this;
    observable.operator = operator;
    return observable;
  }
}


Observable.of(42)
  .let(o => new MyObservable(o))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot do that. You might need to do some monkey patching and do something like

`Observable.prototype.customOperator = /*blabla*/`

this way everything subclassing Observable will have customOperator.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to go with that. I was hoping there was a cleaner solution.

Comment: Hehe i m struggling with The opposite. I am trying to find a dirty but quicker way to fix this http://stackoverflow.com/q/34534616/314407