# How to append a unique_id to my express node logs with winston without refactoring everything?

Tags: node.js, logging, express, winston, unique-id

I've an Express app. I'd like to trace all the loggings that were made by a single request.

Apache has a module called `mod_unique_id` which injects in the request headers a special one containing a unique hash. I'd like to use such hash when logging (anything).

For example if an user is assigned by apache the unique_id valued "abcdefg" and somewhere in my code (controller, model, or anything) i generate a debug log i'd like to have "abcdefg" attached to every log entry.

The only idea that pops in my mind is to create a logger instance using `app.use()` and pass that logger instance to ALL the functions that are needed (models,libs etc) to generate the proper response.

Unfortunately this will cause me to rewrite a lot of the code to let old functions accept this new logger instance.

Does anyone know a better way of having a single "logger" instance per "request" which is accessible somehow without passing this "per-request-created-logger" to anything ?

PS: I'm currently using `winston` to log

Comment: I don;t remember how modules are loaded in `node.js`, but hopefully once a module is loaded, if you modify that in another module, the changes should be visible everywhere. If that-s the case, then you could wrap an advice around the `winston` module, or whichever `winston` method you need. Here are three libraries for aspect oriented programming : https://github.com/cujojs/meld, https://github.com/mgechev/aspect.js, https://github.com/antivanov/jsAspect. The advice function replaces your function without ever modifying it. It is similar to spy in `sinon.js`.

Comment: if you did that, wouldn't it affect other requests as well?

Comment: https://github.com/boldrocket/winston-express-request-logger

Comment: Hey, I've been dealing with the same issue, couldn't find a proper solution, any new insights?

Comment: Hello have you found any solution for this?