# Logging nodejs microservices application with winston

Tags: node.js, logging, microservices, elastic-stack, winston

I wrote server side application that is devided to serveral microservices all of them currentlly written in nodejs. Im using winston as my logging library. Im using also elk to monitor my logs. Recently, i discovered i cant monitor my logs comfortably, and i need a way to view in the kibana the request all the way in my microservices. I mean, i want to view all the logs from the one the request entered the first microservice, until she sent back from the last microservice it went threw. I dont have unique id to my requests or entities that sent, so i need to generate new unique id to each request. but i dont want to add the generated id to each method in my application. There is an elegant solution to do this without changing all my logs? Thanks alot.

Comment: I found similar topics:
read also  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42810364/how-to-track-data-in-nodejs-with-microservices) post
And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534616/how-to-append-a-unique-id-to-my-express-node-logs-with-winston-without-refactori?rq=1)